# Trying to solve an implicit equation, Mathematica gives the equation itself as output

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, implicit

The equation that I am trying solve is:

`-1.+1.77245 E^x^2 Erfc[-\[Lambda]] (1. \[Lambda]+(1.77245 E^x^2 \[Lambda] Erfc[-10. \[Lambda]] ((0.56419 E^-x^2)/Erfc[-\[Lambda]]+(1.78412 E^-x^2)/Erfc[0.316228 \[Lambda]]))/(0.1 +1.77245 E^x^2 \[Lambda] Erfc[-10. \[Lambda]])-(1.78412 E^-x^2)/Erfc[0.316228 \[Lambda]])`

I want to solve this for `{\[Lambda], x}` but Solve is unable to give an solution and even with an value of x, NSolve is unable to give me a solution for `\[Lambda]` (x is the physical domain, I was planning to parametrize the equation over discrete values of x). It simply shows the command itself in the output. Does it mean it can't find the solution? And are there any other methods I should try to get a solution?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. **1** There is no equation without an equal sign. **2** If `Lambda` and `x` are two variables, you will need two equations to solve for both. Please edit and improve your post.

Comment: If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[λ_, x_] = -1. + 1.77245 E^
       x^2 Erfc[-λ] (1. λ + (1.77245 E^
            x^2 λ Erfc[-10. λ] ((0.56419 E^-x^2)/
              Erfc[-λ] + (1.78412 E^-x^2)/
              Erfc[0.316228 λ]))/(0.1 + 
           1.77245 E^x^2 λ Erfc[-10. λ]) - (1.78412 E^-x^2)/
         Erfc[0.316228 λ]) // Rationalize // FullSimplify;

eqn = f[λ, x] == 0 // FullSimplify

(* 3544900000 E^x^2 λ (1 + Erf[λ]) == 
 2869 + (70898000 (178412 (1 + Erf[λ]) + 
     56419 Erfc[(79057 λ)/250000]))/((2000 + 
     35449 E^x^2 λ Erfc[-10 λ]) Erfc[(79057 λ)/250000]) *)
```

To [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for `λ` given `x`

```
pts = Table[{x, SolveValues[{eqn, 0 < λ < 3/10}, λ][[1]]}, {x,
    0, 2, 1/5}]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {x, 0, 2}, {λ, 0, 0.3},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, λ})],
 ListPlot[Tooltip[#, N@#] & /@ pts, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Let us draw it by

```
ContourPlot[-1. +  1.77245 E^x^2 Erfc[-\[Lambda]] (1. \[Lambda] + (1.77245 E^
      x^2 \[Lambda] Erfc[-10. \[Lambda]] ((0.56419 E^-x^2)/
        Erfc[-\[Lambda]] + (1.78412 E^-x^2)/
        Erfc[0.316228 \[Lambda]]))/(0.1 + 
     1.77245 E^
       x^2 \[Lambda] Erfc[-10. \[Lambda]]) - (1.78412 E^-x^2)/
   Erfc[0.316228 \[Lambda]]) == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {\[Lambda],
 -0.5,  0.5}, PlotPoints -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

and a warning about `WorkingPrecision`. Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the equation does not have an explicit solution for [Lambda] and x. In such cases, numerical methods can be used to find an approximate solution. As you have already tried using NSolve and it did not provide a solution, you can try using other numerical methods such as FindRoot or NMinimize to find an approximate solution.

You can use FindRoot to find a numerical solution for [Lambda] for a given value of x. For example:

x = 0.5;

FindRoot[-1. + 1.77245 E^x^2 Erfc[-[Lambda]] (1. [Lambda] + (1.77245 E^x^2 [Lambda] Erfc[-10. [Lambda]] ((0.56419 E^-x^2)/Erfc[-[Lambda]] + (1.78412 E^-x^2)/Erfc[0.316228 [Lambda]]))/(0.1 + 1.77245 E^x^2 [Lambda] Erfc[-10. [Lambda]]) - (1.78412 E^-x^2)/Erfc[0.316228 [Lambda]]), {[Lambda], 1}]

This will give you an approximate value of [Lambda] for x = 0.5.

Similarly, you can use NMinimize to find an approximate solution for both [Lambda] and x. For example:

NMinimize[{(-1. + 1.77245 E^x^2 Erfc[-[Lambda]] (1. [Lambda] + (1.77245 E^x^2 [Lambda] Erfc[-10. [Lambda]] ((0.56419 E^-x^2)/Erfc[-[Lambda]] + (1.78412 E^-x^2)/Erfc[0.316228 [Lambda]]))/(0.1 + 1.77245 E^x^2 [Lambda] Erfc[-10. [Lambda]]) - (1.78412 E^-x^2)/Erfc[0.316228 [Lambda]])^2, {x, [Lambda]}}]

This will minimize the squared error between the left-hand side and right-hand side of the equation to find an approximate solution for both [Lambda] and x.

In summary, if an explicit solution cannot be found, numerical methods can be used to find an approximate solution for implicit equations.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful